# Accessing world bank data indicators and using pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access the world bank data for a range of health indicators.

To access the world bank data the following code is used:

Imports:

```
import wbdata
import datetime
```

See the different indicators:

```
wbdata.get_indicator(source=16) #Source 16 gives indicators for health.
```

This returns the following:

```
SP.DYN.TFRT.IN          Fertility rate, total (births per woman)
SP.DYN.SMAM.MA          Mean age at first marriage, male
SP.DYN.SMAM.FE          Mean age at first marriage, female
```

To access data for a particular country or countries for a time period the following code is used:

```
data_dates = (datetime.datetime(2015,1,1), datetime.datetime(2015,1,1))

top_20_data = wbdata.get_dataframe({'SP.DYN.TFRT.IN':'Fertility rate, total (births per woman)','SP.DYN.SMAM.MA':'Mean age at first marriage, male'}, 
                            country=('BE','BG','CZ','DK','DE','EE','IE','GR','ES','FR','HR','IT','CY','LV','LT','LU',
                                     'HU','MT','NL','AT','PL','PT','RO','SI','SK','FI','SE','GBR'), 
                            data_date=data_dates, 
                            convert_date=False, keep_levels=True)
```

What I want to do is input each indicator into the data frame and each description.

What I have tried to do is create a small sample pandas data frame:

```
data = {'Indicator': ['SP.DYN.TFRT.IN', 'SP.DYN.SMAM.MA', 'SP.DYN.SMAM.MA'],
 'Description': ['Fertility rate, total (births per woman)', 'Mean age at first marriage, male', 'Mean age at first marriage, female']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Indicator', 'Description'])
```

and pass this to wdata.get_daframe like this:

```
top_20_data = wbdata.get_dataframe({df['Indicator']:df['Description']}, 
                            country=('BE','BG','CZ','DK','DE','EE','IE','GR','ES','FR','HR','IT','CY','LV','LT','LU',
                                     'HU','MT','NL','AT','PL','PT','RO','SI','SK','FI','SE','GBR'), 
                            data_date=data_dates, 
                            convert_date=False, keep_levels=True)
```

but I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I have had a look online but there but not found anything particularly useful.

Comment: You are supposed to call `wbdata.get_dataframe()` with a `dictionary` containing a `key` (indicator) and a `value` (description). Right now you are sending in two `Series` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `DataFrame` to dictionary:

```
d = dict(df.values)
#another solution
#d = df.set_index('Indicator')['Description'].to_dict()
top_20_data = wbdata.get_dataframe(d, 
                            country=('BE','BG','CZ','DK','DE','EE','IE','GR','ES','FR','HR','IT','CY','LV','LT','LU',
                                     'HU','MT','NL','AT','PL','PT','RO','SI','SK','FI','SE','GBR'), 
                            data_date=data_dates, 
                            convert_date=False, keep_levels=True)
```